# What is the correct way to check if blazor is running in client side or server side with javascript?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I want to have a function that will run some javascript code only when it's on blazor server side.

e.g.

```
window.Foo = function(){
    if(blazorIsServerSide){
        // do something
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to check if blazor is running in the server side?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this check in JavaScript, you could try

```
window.wasmBinaryFile === undefined
```

Edit: Additional test

```
window.Blazor.reconnect !== undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be exactly what you meant, but you can do it using javascript interop in a blazor component.

```
<button @onclick="@onClick"> Click </button>

@code {

    [Inject]
    protected IJSRuntime jsRuntime { get; set; }

    private void onClick()
    {
        var isWebAssembly = this.jsRuntime is IJSInProcessRuntime;
    }
}
```